# akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException while running Lagom HelloWorld example

Tags: java, scala, akka, lagom

I have a problem while trying my hands on the Hello World example explained [here](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/java/GettingStartedSbt.html).

Kindly note that I have just modified the `HelloEntity.java` file to be able to return something other than "Hello, World!". Most certain my changes are taking time and hence I am getting  the below Timeout error.
I am currently trying (doing a PoC) on a single node to understand the Lagom framework and do not have liberty to deploy multiple nodes.

I have also tried modifying the default lagom.circuit-breaker in application.conf "call-timeout = 100s" however, this does not seem to have helped.

Following is the exact error message for your reference:

> *{"name":"akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://hello-impl-application/system/sharding/HelloEntity#1074448247]] after [5000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message of type \"com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.persistence.CommandEnvelope\".","detail":"akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://hello-impl-application/system/sharding/HelloEntity#1074448247]] after [5000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message of type \"com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.persistence.CommandEnvelope\".\n\tat akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$.$anonfun$defaultOnTimeout$1(AskSupport.scala:595)\n\tat akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$.$anonfun$apply$1(AskSupport.scala:605)\n\tat akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:140)\n\tat scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:866)\n\tat scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:109)\n\tat scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor.execute$(BatchingExecutor.scala:103)\n\tat scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:864)\n\tat akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:328)\n\tat akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.executeBucket$1(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:279)\n\tat akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:283)\n\tat akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:235)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n"}*

**Question:** Is there a way to increase the akka Timeout by modifying the application.conf or any of the java source files in the Hello World project? Can you please help me with the exact details.
Thanks in advance for you time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call timeout is the timeout for circuit breakers, which is configured using `lagom.circuit-breaker.default.call-timeout`. But that's not what is timing out above, the thing that is timing out above is the request to your `HelloEntity`, that timeout is configured using `lagom.persistence.ask-timeout`. The reason why there's a timeout on requests to entities is because in a multi-node environment, your entities are sharded across nodes, so an ask on them may go to another node, which is why a timeout is needed in case that node is not responding.

All that said, I don't think changing the `ask-timeout` will solve your problem. If you have a single node, then your entities should respond instantly if everything is working ok.

- Is that the only error you're seeing in the logs?
- Are you seeing this in devmode (ie, using the `runAll` command), or are you running the Lagom service some other way?
- Is your database responding?

Comment: Thanks for the response James. Following is the answer to your questions:
#1: No, I am not seeing any other error messages in the log.
#2: Yes, I am running runAll command only.
#3: Yes, there seems to be no problem with the database. The original "Hello, World!" seem to work like a charm. However, I see the above exception when I add my modifications to the HelloEntity.java (which I know would take more than 30 Sec to execute).

Comment: For the sake of trying, how do I set `lagom.persistence.ask-timeout`?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks James for the help/pointer.
Adding following lines to resources/application.conf did the trick for me:

```
lagom.persistence.ask-timeout=30s
hello {
..
..
    call-timeout = 30s
    call-timeout = ${?CIRCUIT_BREAKER_CALL_TIMEOUT}
..
}
```

A `Call` is a Service-to-Service communication. That’s a SeviceClient communicating to a remote server. It uses a circuit breaker. It is a extra-service call.

An `ask` (in the context of lagom.persistence) is sending a command to a persistent entity. That happens across the nodes insied your Lagom service. It is not using circuit breaking. It is an intra-service call.